# Solve for $\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve for $\theta$ in $\sqrt{\left[(1-\sin(2\theta))\tan{(\theta+\pi/2)}\right]^2+(\sin{(2\theta)}-1)^2}=d$

I have to solve in order to get some information about the work I'm doing, but I don't know how to solve it and wolframalpha doesn't say the answer.

Comment: Is it https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+for+%5Ctheta+in+%5Csqrt%7B%5Cleft%5B(1-%5Csin(2%5Ctheta))%5Ctan%7B(%5Ctheta%2B%5Cpi%2F2)%7D%5Cright%5D%5E2%2B(%5Csin%7B(2%5Ctheta)%7D-1)%5E2%7D%3Dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left side simplifies a lot.  First factor the $(1-\sin 2\theta)$ out of the square root:

$$(\sin 2\theta -1)\sqrt{\tan(\theta +\frac{\pi}{2})^2 + 1 }= \pm d.$$

(I write $\pm d$ to get rid of absolute value bars.)  Then since $\tan^2 x+1 = \sec^2 x$, we have

$$(\sin 2\theta -1)\sqrt{\sec\left(\theta +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2} = (\sin 2\theta -1)\sec\left(\theta +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)  =(\sin 2\theta -1)\csc \theta = \pm d.$$

Then by double angle formula:

$$(2\sin\theta \cos \theta -1)\csc \theta = 2\cos\theta -\csc \theta = \pm d.$$

And that's as far as I can go without knowing $d$.